# How to insert a new key value pair in existing associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having following associative array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 9def02e6337b888d6dbe5617a172c18d
            [user_first_name] => Ashutosh
            [user_last_name] => Modi
            [user_email] => ashutosh.modi@gmail.com
            [user_status] => enable
            [user_subscription] => lifetime
            [user_registered_type] => online
            [user_reg_date] => 1325581397
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => a6d22e4cc3f65778a60b359842bcec82
            [user_first_name] => Dilip
            [user_last_name] => Modi
            [user_email] => dm.modi@gmail.com
            [user_status] => enable
            [user_subscription] => period
            [user_registered_type] => online
            [user_reg_date] => 1325152066
        )


)
```

It is having two keys. Now I'm having another array named `$user_data` which has the following output:

```
Array
(
    [user_state] => Rajasthan
    [user_city] => Jhunjhunu
)
```

I want to add this key value pair to the above array. Above array is just first iteration of for loop so the above values get inserted into first array element. the second array element will have somethong different values. I want the result in following manner. Can you help me in achieving this? Thanks in advance.

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 9def02e6337b888d6dbe5617a172c18d
                [user_first_name] => Ashutosh
                [user_last_name] => Modi
                [user_email] => ashutosh.modi@gmail.com
                [user_status] => enable
                [user_subscription] => lifetime
                [user_registered_type] => online
                [user_reg_date] => 1325581397
                [user_state] => Rajasthan
                [user_city] => Jhunjhunu
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => a6d22e4cc3f65778a60b359842bcec82
                [user_first_name] => Dilip
                [user_last_name] => Modi
                [user_email] => dm.modi@gmail.com
                [user_status] => enable
                [user_subscription] => period
                [user_registered_type] => online
                [user_reg_date] => 1325152066
                 [user_state] => Tamilnadu
                [user_city] => Chennai
            )


    )
```

Comment: use array_merge() function take look of it http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: I tried array_mergerge but it didn't work. May be I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    foreach($user_data as $key => $val){
        $original_array[$key]['user_state'] = $val['user_state'];
        $original_array[$key]['user_city'] = $val['user_city'];
    }
```

assuming the 2 arrays have the same keys

Answer (score 3):

Try with `array_merge`

```
foreach ($users as &$user)
{
    $user = array_merge($user, $user_data);
}

var_dump($users);
```

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Always with you from Turkey. May Allah help you. Fi emanillah ehi ;)